# Linux bash if else for command output not continuing?

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for x in $(cat $1)
do
  wget --recursive -R jpg,bmp,gif,png $x
  cd $x
  for e in $(ls)
  do
    a=`file $e | getfield 2`
    if [ $a == "directory" ]
    then
      for enn in $(ls $a)
      do
        cat $a/$enn | emailaddr
      done
    else
      cat $e | emailaddr
    fi
    done
  cd ..
done
```

Where getfield is a bash script like so

```
#!/usr/bin/env 
cut -d' ' -f$1 oo
```

I think it's useful to note that I'm just trying to learn shell scripting to make life easier and not write code in ruby or some other language that involves executing shell commands and piping the output when I can just do it this way.

I know that my script is getting hung when I do a=`file $e | getfield 2`, but I can't seem to figure out why. Could somebody clarify this for me?

Comment: we can't either run your code or understand it. please provide a better example. another suggestion is replace all your `ls` to be `*` or `$a/*` or so.

Comment: sorry, i should have thought of that. i used my localhost webserver, and the only file in folder localhost/ is index.html. there are no directories, and therefore the first if should not be triggered, and the else should be.

Comment: It might be more convenient to declare `getfield` as a function rather than a script in a separate file, like that: `getfield() { cut -d' ' -f$1 oo; }`

Comment: Aside: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Also, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Also, run your code through http://shellcheck.net/; no reason to be bothering humans for advice until you've fixed the problems even a machine could find. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `getfield` at all. `bash` has a built-in test to check if a file is a directory.

```
if [[ -d $e ]]; then
```

The script itself is better written as

```
while IFS= read -r x; do
  wget --recursive -R jpg,bmp,gif,png "$x"
  cd "$x"
  for e in *; do
    if [[ -d $e ]]; then
      cat "$e"/* | emailaddr
    else
      emailaddr < "$e"
    fi
    done
  cd ..
done < "$1"
```